# Ajax fires only once,and the javascript file is loaded only once

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, load

Basically, I am trying to load the html and JavaScript file for each subpage on my website with ajax. However, the JavaScript file only loads for the first subpage that is clicked on. If I click on the next subpage, only the html document for that loads, but the javascript does not. This is from looking at the firebug console: Clicking on about first, then clicking on contact:

```
GET http:..../about.html?t=0.19504348425731444
GET http:..../about.js?t=0.8286968088896364
GET http:..../contact.html?t=0.8467537141462976
(!!!NO GET FOR contact.js!!!)
```

Anyways, I tried using live() to bind the click event but it still doesn't work.Here's the relevant snippets of my code:

```
$('.subpage').live('click',function(){
$('#main').css({'cursor':'crosshair'});
    navsubpage = true;
    subpage = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.subpage').each(function(index) {
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).fadeOut('500');
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'select').fadeOut('500');
        });
    $('#'+subpage+'h').css({'background-color':'#000','display':'block'});
    $('#'+subpage+'h').animate({'width':'375px','top':'120px','left':'100px','font-size':'400%'},'500');
    subtop = $('#'+subpage+'h').css('top');
    subleft = $('#'+subpage+'h').css('left');
    $('#pane').css({'border-left-width':'0px'});
    $('#nav').css({'background':'url("images/'+$(this).attr('id')+'.jpg") no-repeat 0px 0px'});
    $('#nav').animate({'left':'0px'},'4000','swing',function(){
    $('#reload').show().delay(500).queue(function(){
    alert("made it");
    $.ajax({
        url: subpage+".js?t=" + Math.random(),
        dataType: 'script',
        type: 'get',
    });
    });
    });
    reload(subpage);

});
$('#main').click(function(){
    if(navsubpage==true){
        $('#main').css({'cursor':'auto'});
        $('#reload').hide();
        $('#pane').css({'border-left-width':'10px'});
        $('#'+subpage+'h').animate({'width':'150px','top':subtop,'left':subleft,'font-size':'200%'},'2000',function(){
        $('#'+subpage+'h').css({'display':'none'})});
        $('#nav').animate({'left':'415px'},'3000','swing', function(){
        $('.subpage').each(function(index) {
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).fadeIn('3000');
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'select').fadeIn('3000');
        });});
    navsubpage = false;
    }
});
```

the reload function loads the html and is working correctly.

I am really new to ajax, javascript...etc. If any of you can help me out, that'll be great.

Comment: please format code either via indent or `s (also see the buttons on the editor) /e: Oh, I see you did now.

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing that you have both the `"?t=" + Math.random()` combined with `cache: true`.

The practice of appending a timestamp to a URL is a common method to *prevent* caching, but then you explicitly tell it that you want it to cache. You might try removing the `cache: true` option, as it looks to be totally superfluous and can only cause problems (the likes of which would resemble what you're describing here).

Comment: Thanks for the tip(I messed with the ajax call a lot in an effort to make the thing work...). I've removed the cache part, but I'm still getting the same problem....:

Comment: Are you sure the `$.ajax()` is getting called? Put an `alert("made it")` or a `console.log("made it")` directly before your `$.ajax()`. Also, what is the value of `subpage` in your code? We're going to need a much more complete code sample to do much else.

Comment: The value for subpage is the name of the page I'm loading (about, contact). I included more code, all code that has to do with the subpage loading and animations. I added the alert - the function is only being called once. So for some reason the code inside $('#reload').show().delay(500).queue(function(){
is not being called once I've clicked once on a .subpage element.  I think the problem may have to do with the #reload div, which is the div onto which the subpage's html and javascript is loaded, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend trying out a jQuery ajax shortcut function [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

It is farly simple and might cut out a lot of uneccesary options you are setting using the full $.ajax() function

Comment: I tried using $getscript() again but it's still not loading subsequent js

Comment: do you mean $.get() ?  because $getscript() will definitely not work.

Comment: I tried both, Getscript and get, they work, but they are only fired once, after the first firing, the code inside  $('#reload').show().delay(500).queue(function(){ doesn't fire for some reason....

Comment: ok, ok, ok, I think I figured it out from what you're saying.  Sounds like you are ending up with multiple items on the page that have the id "reload".  DOM element id's have to be unique.  only one element on a page at one time can have the id "reload".  You are suppose to use classes to share selectors between multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys - in the end I just decided to not mess with the queue stuff. I still don't understand why it works, but I just took out the ajax and placed it outside of $('#reload').show().delay(500).queue(function(){, eliminating the delay and queue stuff and making the ajax a separate snippet of code. now it loads correctly.